# How do I destroy an object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I have a timer class, that I designed to fire once, and (optimally) delete itself. Is there a way for me to implement that self-deletion?

```
class timer:
        def __init__(self, duration, function, args):
            self.duration = duration
            self.function = function
            self.args = args
        def start(self):
            self.time = time.time()
            self.validity = True    
        def check(self):
            if(int(self.time)+self.duration < time.time() ):
                self.function(self.args)
                self.validity = False
        def __del__(self):
            print("timer destroyed")
```

Comment: Python has garbage collection. Unless you have very specific requirements, it's not even meaningful for an object to delete itself. The best you can do is make sure there are no variables or objects that contain a reference to the timer after you're done with it.

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the similar approach.

An `object.__del__(self)` can be called to destroy an instance.

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __del__(self):
...         print "deleted"
... 
>>> test = Test()
>>> del test
deleted
```

Object is not deleted unless all of its references are removed

Also, From Python official doc reference:

> del x doesn’t directly call x.**del**() — the former decrements the
>   reference count for x by one, and the latter is only called when x‘s
>   reference count reaches zero

What you would need in your solution is to use something like `del object` where the object is the instance that you want to remove.

Comment: Is there a way I can call del from the another method. IE. timer.check, if fired, would delete the entire timer object?

Comment: `del` only removes the local or global reference to the object. The object is deleted by the garbage collector when the reference count of the object is zero, unless you manually run the garbage collector you cannot control when it will be deleted

Comment: @IncredibleCoder I don't think so. To call a del inside a method means that an object would have to delete itself which simply makes no sense. My recommendation would be to remove it in the main loop. Also, note the important comment by lain above

Comment: Take this simple example: `a = Test(); a.some_method_that_deletes_itself();`. Even if you for some reason ran `del self` in the method the object would still have a reference to it `a`. If you also had `b = a` somewhere then running `del a` would not delete the object as there is another reference to it now `b`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using None? something like this:

```
timer = None
```